# Write a single column Array in JSON

Tags: java, json

I know how to write with the typical synthax a JSONArray like this:

```
{
    "maxUsers":100,
    "maxTextLength":2000,
    "maxFileSize":2000,
    "services":
    [
        {
            "serviceName":"Яндекc",
            "className":"YandexConnector.class",
            "isEnabled":true
        },

        {
            "serviceName":"Google",
            "className":"GoogleConnector.class",
            "isEnabled":false
        }
    ]
}
```

But would there be a way in Java to write to jsonfile a single column Arraylist like this contaianing only elements?;

```
{
    "maxUsers"
    "maxTextLength"
    "maxFileSize"
    "services"
    [
        {
          "Яндекc",
            "YandexConnector.class",
            true
        },

        {
           "Google",
          "GoogleConnector.class",

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What you've written is simply not valid JSON. It would have to be a pretty faulty serializer to be able to write invalid JSON that no other program will read.

Comment: did you figure out how to do what you wanted, MaelPJ?  Please accept and/or upvote if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an array for the top-most element of your JSON data file or object.  When you do that, JSON requires you comma separate the elements.  You can mix one value elements with objects with more value elements in the array.  An example might look like:

```
[
    "simple string element one",
    "simple string element two",
    "simple string element three",
    {
        "name": "object one",
        "type": "JSON object"
    },
    {
        "name": "object two",
        "type": "JSON object"
    },
    {
        "name": "object three",
        "type": "JSON object with array",
        "arrayData": [
            "another array simple string element",
            {
                "name": "array JSON object one",
                "type": "array JSON object",
                "valueProperty": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "array JSON object one",
                "type": "array JSON object",
                "valueProperty": true
            }
        ]
    },
]
```